# Use Excel to look for 2 string values over 2 columns and in one row and return the cell value if there is a match on either of the lookup strings

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013, worksheet-function

I would like to have some help with creating an MS Excel 2013 formula that would do the following.
It should look for two string values over 2 columns in one row and should return the cell value of the cell in which the string value was found.

Sorry if I am not explaining myself correctly. Here is an example of the dataset and my expected result

My Dataset have 2 columns A and B but I would like only 1 output in C if *ocn*   OR  *ocm* exist.

I would like to use this formula to normalise this data set.

```
A                   B                   C (Result for ocm or ocn)
(OCoLC)911180191    (OCoLC)ocn911180191 (OCoLC)ocn911180191
(OCoLC)ocn911180196 (OCoLC)911180196    (OCoLC)ocn911180196
(OCoLC)911495338    (OCoLC)ocm911495338 (OCoLC)ocm911495338
(OCoLC)ocm794701569 (OCoLC)794701569    (OCoLC)ocm794701569
```

[Click to see a picture of what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfF5V.png)

Comment: Look into index/match.

Answer (score 0):

**In C2 Cell**

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(A2,{"*ocn*","*ocm*"})),A2,IF(SUM(COUNTIF(B2,{"*ocn*","*ocm*"})),B2,""))
```

Or

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/MATCH({"*ocn*","*ocm*"},A2:B2,0),A2:B2),"")
```

Or

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH({"*ocn*","*ocm*"},A2:B2),A2:B2),"")
```

Or

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"*ocn*","*ocm*"},A2))),A2,IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"*ocn*","*ocm*"},B2))),B2,""))
```

Drag the C2 Cell formula down.